# Convert WrappedArray column with rows into a Dataframe with rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I want to extract a WrappedArray element in below dataframe that consists of couple of rows into a Dataframe consisting of same number of rows.

The whole dataset df being passed into printArray function is as below:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|SECURITY_ID|combined_list                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|290X2      |[[290X2, 3FA34789, 0800TS, BOXXBU, BOXXMP, 0101, 5279, 290X2, 18063, P, , 0, 0], [290X2, 3FA34782, 0800TS, BOXXBU, BOXXMP, 0102, 5322, 290X2, -863, N, , 0, 0], [290X2, 3FA34789, 0800TS, BOXXBU, BOXXMP, 0101, 5279, 290X2, -108926, N, , 0, 0]]|
|35G71      |[[35G71, 92115301, 08036C, BOXXBU, BOXXMP, 0154, 8380, 35G71, 8003, P, , 0, 0], [35G71, 92115302, 08036C, BOXXBU, BOXXMP, 0144, 8382, 35G71, -2883, N, , 0, 0]]                                                                                  |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The result I want for each Security should be as below:

```
    Security: 290X2
+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
SECURITY_ID|ACCOUNT_NO |COSTCENTER|    BU|   MPU|LONG_IND|SHORT_IND|QUANTITY|POS_NEG_QUANTITY|PROCESSED|ALLOC_QUANTITY|NET_QUANTITY|
+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
290X2      |3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|      18063|               P|         |             0|           0|
290X2      |3FA34782|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0102|     5322|       -863|               N|         |             0|           0|
290X2      |3FA34789|    0800TS|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0101|     5279|    -108926|               N|         |             0|           0|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+-------------+

    Security: 35G71
+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
SECURITY_ID|ACCOUNT_NO |COSTCENTER|    BU|   MPU|LONG_IND|SHORT_IND|QUANTITY|POS_NEG_QUANTITY|PROCESSED|ALLOC_QUANTITY|NET_QUANTITY|
+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+--------------+------------+
35G71|92115301   |    08036C|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0154|     8380      |8003    |               P|         |             0|           0|
35G71|92115302   |    08036C|BOXXBU|BOXXMP|    0144|     8382      |   -2883|               N|         |             0|           0|
+-------------+----------+----------+------+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------+-------------+
```

I try opening the second element in df i.e. t(1) and convert to a dataframe but am failing. Used Case class also as shown below:

```
case class ExplodeWrappedArray(SECURITY_ID: String, ACCOUNT_NO: String, COSTCENTER: String, BU: String, MPU: String, LONG_IND: String, SHORT_IND: String, QUANTITY: String, POS_NEG_QUANTITY: String, PROCESSED: String, ALLOC_QUANTITY: Integer, NET_QUANTITY: Integer)

def printArray(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
    println("Hello")

//This fails
    df.foreach(t => t(1).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray(ExplodeWrappedArray)])

//This works
    //df.foreach(t => openList((t(1))))
  }
```

Pass t(1) to openList and print the WrappedArray straight up but I want to open the array and convert to a dataframe.

```
def openList(a: mutable.WrappedArray[ExplodeWrappedArray]): Unit = {
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    println("Hello")

    //This works 
    println(a)

    //This fails
    val b = a.toDF("SECURITY_ID", "ACCOUNT_NO", "COSTCENTER", "BU", "MPU", "LONG_IND", "SHORT_IND", "QUANTITY", "POS_NEG_QUANTITY", "PROCESSED", "ALLOC_QUANTITY", "NET_QUANTITY")
    b.printSchema()
    b.show()
  }
```

Comment: could you simplify the question a bit? What's the output of printSchema?

Comment: The printschema is failing bcoz DF isn’t created. I want to create DF, that’s what my question is for.